# How to Detect Partial Text within a Selector using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am using CasperJS for functional testing, and I want to check if an error message is displaying in a page.

**I am using:**

```
test.assertSelectorHasText('#iccid-error', 'CC-ICCID-01');
```

That works fine but only if I use the whole text (not part of it).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#assertselectorhastext), the CasperJS function `assertSelectorHasText()`:

> Asserts that given text exists in elements matching the provided [selector expression](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/selectors.html#selectors).

In other words, this function will work for full and partial strings, and the test will pass if the string exists within the element.

I ran a simple test to verify the accuracy of the function.

**Command Line:**

```
casperjs casperjs.js
```

**Result:**

```
# How to Detect Partial Text within a Selector using CasperJS
PASS Find "CC" within the selector "#iccid-error"
PASS Find "CC-ICCID" within the selector "#iccid-error"
PASS Find "CC-ICCID-01" within the selector "#iccid-error"
PASS How to Detect Partial Text within a Selector using CasperJS (3 tests)
```

**casperjs.js:**

```
phantom.casperTest = true;

var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.test.begin('How to Detect Partial Text within a Selector using CasperJS', 3, function (test) {
  casper.start('https://example.com/test.php', function () {
    test.assertSelectorHasText('#iccid-error', 'CC');
    test.assertSelectorHasText('#iccid-error', 'CC-ICCID');
    test.assertSelectorHasText('#iccid-error', 'CC-ICCID-01');
  }).run(function () {
    test.done();
  });
});

casper.on('run.complete', function () {
  this.exit();
});
```

**example.com/test.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="iccid-error">CC-ICCID-01</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

As a result, I can conclude that the function `assertSelectorHasText()` does in fact search for partial strings in the element matching the selector given.